# Replacing day part in Date with another number in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-formatting

i am trying to replace a day part in a date value. say for example

```
select TRUNC(SYSDATE) from dual;
```

Result: 28/11/2014

I wanted to replace only the 28 with another number value(X). So i can arrive the result like X/11/2014.

Can you please help me?

Thanks in Advance,

Murugan.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
trunc(sysdate,'MM') + (x-1)
```

would do it.  `trunc(sysdate,'MM')` returns the first of the month.  Then you add however many days you want to get the date that you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TO_DATE('01' || SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),3))
FROM DUAL
WHERE TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') = '25';
```

Comment: I like this one -- it allows to keep the time if you need.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a character then you can use below query:

```
SELECT 'X'||SUBSTR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),3) FROM DUAL;
```

If you want to replace with some other number then:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(21||SUBSTR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),3),'DD-MON-YY') FROM DUAL;
```